# How to replace function params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I'm using the following code to make ajax call where the form data is passed as params.

```
//ajax call
function restServiceCall(origin,destination,tripType,dateDepart,dateReturn){

    dataString = 'origin='+ origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&tripType='+tripType;

     $.jsonp({
          "url": flightURL,
          callbackParameter:jsonpCallBack,
          data: dataString,
    beforeSend:function(){$('#loadingdiv').show()},
           "success": function(data) {
                        if(data.error != null){
                            $('#errtitle').html('<h2 class="pgtitle">Error !! &nbsp;'+data.error+'</h2>').show();
                            $("#displaydiv,loadingdiv").hide();
                        }else{
                          renderData (data,dateDepart,dateReturn);
                      }
           },

            "error": function(xOptions, textStatus) {
               $('#errtitle').html('<h2 class="pgtitle">Sorry the service you are looking for is currently unavailable</h2>').show();
               $("#displaydiv,loadingdiv").hide();
           }
 });
}
```

Besides making the call from form I also use it in the following function wherein I just need to pass either the dateDepart/dateReturn as params.

```
//for pagination
$('.pagenation a').bind('click',function(){
        var numDays = 7;
        var self = $(this);

        var dateTemp = self.parents(':eq(1)').attr('id')=="onewaytripdiv"? parseDate(dateDepart):parseDate(dateReturn);

        if(self.hasClass('left')){
            var tempDepDate = removeNumOfDays(dateTemp,numDays);
        }else{
            var tempDepDate = addNumOfDays(dateTemp,numDays);
        }
        var changedDate = tempDepDate.getDate()+' '+cx.monthNamesShort[tempDepDate.getMonth()]+' '+tempDepDate.getFullYear();
        if(self.parents(':eq(1)').attr('id')=="onewaytripdiv"){
            dateDepart = changedDate;
        }else{
            dateReturn = changedDate;
        }   
    restServiceCall(origin,destination,tripType,dateDepart,dateReturn);
});
```

I would like to remove the params in the function call, as the params may vary. Please suggest an alternative to pass the params.

Answer (score 0):

How about passing an array of parameters instead? And then pass another value, such as an integer to indicate to the function what to expect in it's parameter array.

e.g

```
restServiceCall(myParams, 0);
```